# Shell script to change lock screen image not working when running from psm1 file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have written the following script to change the lock screen image.

```
   Write-Output "Lock Screen Changing..."  
   
   try {

       $RegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP"  

       $LockScreenPath = "LockScreenImagePath"
       $LockScreenStatus = "LockScreenImageStatus"
       $LockScreenUrl = "LockScreenImageUrl"

       $StatusValue = "1"

       $LockScreenImageValue = "C:\temp\abc.png"

       if (!(Test-Path $RegKeyPath))
       {
           Write-Host "Creating registry path $($RegKeyPath)."
           New-Item -Path $RegKeyPath -Force | Out-Null
       }

           
       Write-Output $RegKeyPath
       
       Write-Output $LockScreenImageValue
       
       New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenStatus -Value $StatusValue -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
       New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenPath -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null
       New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenUrl -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null

       Write-Output "Lock Changes done...."
   }
   catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred:"
        Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
   }
```

The above script works (Lock screen changes) fine when I paste the script in Powershell directly. But when I execute this code keeping inside a function in the psm1 file, it does not work. The lock screen does not get changed. However, I can see this "Lock Screen Changing..." means the function is executing correctly. I can't see any error. Can anyone please help me with this? Why the same script is not working?

Note that, I am using Windows 11 and tried administrator mode always.

Here is my module code steps

1. Running following command first
   `powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0Win11.ps1" -include "%~dp0Win11.psm1" -preset "master-preset.txt" -log "NSX-Install.log`
2. Code inside the Win11.ps1

```
$PSCommandArgs = @()

Function AddOrRemoveTweak($tweak) {
    If ($tweak[0] -eq "!") {
        # If the name starts with exclamation mark (!), exclude the tweak from selection
        $script:tweaks = $script:tweaks | Where-Object { $_ -ne $tweak.Substring(1) }
    } ElseIf ($tweak -ne "") {
        # Otherwise add the tweak
        $script:tweaks += $tweak
    }
}

# Parse and resolve paths in passed arguments
$i = 0
While ($i -lt $args.Length) {
    If ($args[$i].ToLower() -eq "-include") {
        # Resolve full path to the included file
        $include = Resolve-Path $args[++$i] -ErrorAction Stop
        $PSCommandArgs += "-include `"$include`""
        # Import the included file as a module
        Import-Module -Name $include -ErrorAction Stop
    } ElseIf ($args[$i].ToLower() -eq "-preset") {
        # Resolve full path to the preset file
        $preset = Resolve-Path $args[++$i] -ErrorAction Stop
        $PSCommandArgs += "-preset `"$preset`""
        # Load tweak names from the preset file
        Get-Content $preset -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object { AddOrRemoveTweak($_.Split("#")[0].Trim()) }
    } ElseIf ($args[$i].ToLower() -eq "-log") {
        # Resolve full path to the output file
        $log = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($args[++$i])
        $PSCommandArgs += "-log `"$log`""
        # Record session to the output file
        Start-Transcript $log
    } Else {
        $PSCommandArgs += $args[$i]
        # Load tweak names from command line
        AddOrRemoveTweak($args[$i])
    }
    $i++
}

# Call the desired tweak functions
$tweaks | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression $_ }
```

3. And the function name (SetLockScreen) is writtent in master-preset.txt
4. And int the psm1 file the function is defined as follows

```
 Function SetLockScreen {
    
    Write-Output "Lock Screen Changing..."
    
    Get-ExecutionPolicy
    
    
    try {

        $RegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP"  

        $LockScreenPath = "LockScreenImagePath"
        $LockScreenStatus = "LockScreenImageStatus"
        $LockScreenUrl = "LockScreenImageUrl"

        $StatusValue = "1"

        $LockScreenImageValue = "C:\temp\abc.png"
        if (!(Test-Path $RegKeyPath))
        {
            Write-Host "Creating registry path $($RegKeyPath)."
            New-Item -Path $RegKeyPath -Force | Out-Null
        }

            
        Write-Output $RegKeyPath
        
        Write-Output $LockScreenImageValue
        
         New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenStatus -Value $StatusValue -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
         New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenPath -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null
         New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenUrl -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null 

        Write-Output "Lock Changes done...."
    }
    catch {
         Write-Host "An error occurred:"
         Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of the module function as well (the full function, including parameters).

Comment: You can also do that in group policy.

Comment: @zett42 updated the description. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I see only one issue, which is there in both the module and the non-module version of the code. You are assigning `$LockScreenImageValue` to both the `LockScreenImagePath` and the `LockScreenImageUrl` registry values.

Comment: Should it create any issues? I noticed the registry values are not being changed. This is the issue.

Comment: I have also tried to set 0 for LockScreenStatus still not changing. But it changes when paste the code directly in PowerShell.